# how to make 2 applications interact

Tags: c++

I've two applications, lets say app1 and app2. if app1 opens a dialog box, app2 needs to know that and send dialog close message to app1 so that user can close the dialog box. I'm wondering how do I achieve this functionality? please note that both apps are running on same machine, was developed using visual c++ and there is no existing communication channel like sockets, named piped or etc between the two.

Comment: You would use a "communication channel like sockets, named piped or etc"

Comment: So... specifically on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: If there is no "communication channel like sockets, named piped or etc", is voodoo an option?

Comment: You want to head in the [Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221375(v=vs.85).aspx) direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you're the developer of both applications, you could simply use window messages in such cases. If you don't want to use communication channels you'll have to figure out the other application's window handle by using FindWindow or similar.

Comment: As my app2, which send close dialog box msg to app1 runs as a service. I read somewhere that on windows vista and 7, I can't call findwindow function to get the handle of app1.